# Where can I plug a method call that populates the viewbag so it is called in every request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project and there is a sidebar in which I show some user information.
I would like to have a method called to generate this information and populate the ViewBag so I can display it.

As far as I know, I could use Globals.asax's Application_BeginRequest method, but it won't allow me to use the ViewBag.

Where can I "plug" this method call so it is called in every request and I can populate the ViewBag?

Edit: please let me know if there is a better way of populating this information

Comment: One way is to create base controller and use it's constructor to populate the `ViewBag` with the data you want.

Comment: Would this be a good practice?

Comment: It's more of a design problem. The most common practice that I know is to create some sort of base class. Is it better than using `ActionFilter` and why - I am not quite sure. But I think this is the common approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an **ActionFilter**:

```
public class IncludeSidebarValuesAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var controller = filterContext.Controller as YourBaseController;

            if (controller != null)
            {
                       controller.ViewBag.YourInfo = LoadSideBarInfo();


            }
        }
    }
```

Then, in your controller you decorate the actions like this:

```
[IncludeSidebarValues]
public ActionResult YourAction(){
---
}
```

Comment: We use this approach to load some things that are used in lots of actions. We have other filters to inject user permission in the ViewModel, making the viewmodel inherit from a base view model with properies like "CanEdit", "CanCreate", "CanDelete". So, the Viewmodels are not cluttered with this logic.

Comment: Is it possible to run for all controllers, without the need of decoration?

Comment: Oscar: You can add it to the GlobalFilters collection.

Answer (score 0):

you can use _Layout.cshtml, it's rendered everytime so your method inside will be executed everytime.

Comment: Yes, the sidebar is inside _layout.cshtml. You mean I should call a controller's action from this file?

Comment: You can call whatever you want, same effect as home.cshtml(for example). Suggest to use static method not from controller as basically it should return view, _layout.cshtml cannot have model. But it depends on weight of importance of data you pass.

Comment: @user2308005 What do you suggest actually? Unless it's some kind of JS function that will be called from the `_Layout` how do you suggest to pass the data from the server side to the `View`?